# How can I log that the item with that id was removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have it logging as just 'removed' and I do not know how to make it specific to each id. 
This is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="apple">
        <label><input type="radio" name="list" value="apple">Apple</label>
        <button class='remove'>delete</button>
    </li>
    <li id="Orange">
        <label><input type="radio" name="list" value="orange">Orange</label>
        <button class='remove'>delete</button>
    </li>
    <li id="pear">
        <label><input type="radio" name="list" value="pear">Pear</label>
        <button class='remove'>delete</button>
    </li>
    <li id="banana">
        <label><input type="radio" name="list" value="banana">Banana</label>
        <button class='remove'>delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my function

```
$("ul").on("click", "button", function() {
    alert('Are you sure you want to remove?'); 
    $(this).fadeOut(400, function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    console.log('removed');
    }); 
});
```

PS. I would like the function to execute in the following order; 
1. User clicks 'delete' 
2. Confirm they are sure
3. Fade out and delete
4. Once removed, log that the item with that 'id' is removed

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please select the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the id of the parent before you remove it.

```
$("ul").on("click", "button", function() {
    alert('Are you sure you want to remove?'); 
    $(this).fadeOut(400, function(){
        var itemID= $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $(this).parent().remove();
        console.log(itemID + " removed");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Ok thank you but I would like to get the id of the parent once it's removed. I would like it to be in this order -- 1.User clicks delete 2. confirm that they are sure 3. fade out then remove 4. After removed log that the item was removed.

Comment: Included more of your code to show that the id of the parent is saved before it's removed and the log happens after.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the id before removing. Try this:

```
 var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
 $(this).parent().remove();
 console.log('removed ['+id+']');
```

As a side note, `alert` is not a confirmation dialog, just an information popup. You should probably use `if(confirm('Are you sure you want to remove?'))`.

Comment: When the user clicks 'delete' I am supposed to confirm, then fade out, then remove. That is why I have the alert. Do you suggest another method?

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Confirm that user wants to delete it

```
var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
if(confirmed){ //..if true
    //.. continue
}
```

Step 2: Fade out, record ID and remove

```
var item = $(this).closest('li'); //get the LI element
var id = item.attr("id");
item.fadeOut("slow", function(){
    //when fade out finishes continue
    item.remove(); //delete the element
    console.log(item.attr('id')); 
});
```

The whole code could look like this for example

```
$('.remove').click(function(){

    var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
    if(confirmed){
        var item = $(this).closest('li');
        var id = item.attr('id');
        item.fadeOut("slow", function(){                
            item.remove();
            console.log("Removed item with ID: " + id);
        });
    }
});
```